# error code: 1046 no database selected when creating database in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error message "error code: 1046 no database selected" using MySQL
Below is the script that I wrote, Any suggestions on why I'm getting the error message?

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Bookstore;

Create Database Bookstore;


Use Bookstore;


Create Table Subject
(SubjectCode    nvarchar(3) Not Null primary key,
Subject nvarchar(15)    Null);

Create Table Book
(ISBN   nvarchar(13)    Not Null primary key,
Title   nvarchar(50)    Null,
Author  nvarchar(30)    Null,
Publisher   nvarchar(30)    Null,
Subject_Code    nvarchar(3) Null References Subject (Subject_Code),
Shelf_Location  nvarchar(7) Null,
Fiction bit Null);


Use Bookstore;
Insert Into Subject
Values
    ('ART', 'Art'),
    ('BSN', 'Business'),
    ('BSS', 'Best Seller'),
    ('EDC', 'Education'),
    ('FNT', 'Fantasy'),
    ('HMR', 'Humor'),
    ('MST', 'Myster'),
    ('PHL', 'Philosophy'),
    ('RLG', 'Religion'),
    ('RMN', 'Romance'),
    ('SCF', 'Science Fiction'),
    ('SLH', 'Self Help');

Use Bookstore;    
Insert Into Book
Values
    ('0-111-11111-1', '89 Years in a Sand Trapxx', 'Beck, Fred', 'Hill and Wang', 'HMR', 'RC-1111', '0'),
    ('0-15-500139-6', 'Business Programming in C', 'Milsspaugh, A.C.', 'The Dryden Press', 'BSN', 'RC-1111', '0'),
    ('0-394-75843-9', 'Cultural Literacy', 'Hirsch, E.D. Jr.', 'Vintage', 'Bss', 'RC-1115', '0'),
    ('0-440-22284-2', 'Five Days in Paris', 'Steel, Daniels', 'Dell Publishing', 'RMN', 'RC-1114', '0'),
    ('0-446-51251-6', 'Megatrends', 'Naisbitt, John', 'Warner Books', 'PHL', 'RC-1114', '0'),
    ('0-446-51652-X', 'Bridges of Madison County', 'Waller, Robert James', 'Warner Books', 'BSS', 'RC-1114', '1'),
    ('0-446-60274-4', 'The Rules', 'Fein/Schneider', 'Warner Books', 'SLH', 'RC-1111', '0'),
    ('0-451-16095-9', 'The Stand', 'King, Stephen', 'Signet', 'MST', 'RC-1113', '0'),
    ('0-452-26011-6', 'Song of Solomon', 'Morrision, Toni', 'Plume/Penguin', 'BSS', 'Rc-1114', '1'),
    ('0-517-59905-8', 'How to Talk to Anyone, Anytime, Anywhere', 'King, Larry', 'Crown', 'SLH', 'RC-1113', '0'),
    ('0-534-26076-4', 'A Quick Guide to the Internet', 'Filus, Steve', 'Intergrated Media Group', 'BSN', 'RC-1111', '0'),
    ('0-553-24484-X', 'Prospering Woman', 'Ross, Ruth', 'Bantam Brooks', 'SLH', 'RC-1111', '0'),
    ('0-670-85332-1', 'How to be Hap-Hap-Happy Like Me', 'Markoe, Merrill', 'Viking', 'HMR', 'RC-1113', '1'),
    ('0-671-67158-8', 'Time Wars', 'Rifkin, Jeremy', 'Simon and Schuster', 'PHL', 'RC-1115', '0'),
    ('0-697-12897-0', 'Quick Basic and QBasic Using Modular Structure', 'Filus, Steve', 'B & E Tech', 'BSN', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-697-21361-7', 'Desktop Publishing Using PageMaker 5.0', 'Filus, Steve', 'B & E Tech', 'BSN', 'RC-1111', '0'),
    ('0-8007-1213-7', 'Secrets of Closing the Sale', 'Ziglar, Zig', 'Revel', 'BSN', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-8041-0753-X', 'The Kitchen God''s Wife', 'Tan, Amy', 'Ivy Books', 'BSS', 'RC-1113', '1'),
    ('0-8109-3158-3', 'Thomas Cole', 'Powell, Earl A.', 'Abrams', 'ART', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-8109-8052-5', 'The Art of Walt Disney', 'Finch, Christopher', 'Albradale', 'Art', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-8487-0504', 'Erica Wilson''s Quilts of America', 'Wilson, Erica', 'Oxmoor House', 'ART', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-87826-2', 'Know Your Lhaso Apso', 'Schneider, Earl', 'The Pet Library LTD', 'SLH', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-89997=087-7', 'Afoot and Afield in Orange County', 'Schad, Jerry', 'Wilderness Press', 'SLH', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-915391-40-6', 'Designing User Interfaces', 'Powell, James E.', 'Micontrend', 'BSN', 'RC-1114', '0'),
    ('0-917849-25-6', 'I am enough', 'Stortz, Margaret', 'Science of Mind', 'PHL', 'RC-115', '0'),
    ('0-934136-27-0', 'Wine Makers Guide', 'Nury/Fugelsang', 'Western Tanager', 'MST', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('0-9616878-6-X', 'Classics, US Aircraft of World War II', 'Meyer, Mark', 'Howell Press', 'ART', 'RC-1112', '0'),
    ('1-55615-484-4', 'Code Complete', 'Mc Connell, Steve', 'Microsoft Press', 'BSN', 'RC-1115', '0'),
    ('1-82423-2218-3', 'The Way', 'Chaney, Elana', 'Tyndale', 'RLG', 'RC-1111', '0');
```

Comment: You should run the script one statement at a time.  That will probably give you all the information you need to find the culprit.

Comment: @steve you use phpMyAdmin? by using  XAMPP?

Comment: @steve , if you use xampp phpmyadmin then first if u have database Bookstore is present then first drop it by GUI interface & after that exluding ur drop query & delete space from all queries & then execute full sql query.

Comment: I've run this script without any issue, it maybe that it's your IDE which is causing the issue? Which application are you using to execute the script?

Comment: I am using MySQL workbench

Comment: If you run the drop command first, and then the rest seperately does that work?

Comment: No I still get the same error

Comment: So I was using execute explain and that's why I was getting the error. Now when I execute it stops at line 18. Insert into book values. Saying that the data is too long for column 'fiction' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

make sure the database is created with command:

```
Create Database dbname
```

Comment: I did in line 2 Create Database Bookstore;